# Angular - datatable redraw table with new data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datatable, angular-cli

i am facing an issue with the angular datatable redraw thing.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-angular-way-tutorial-pagination-not-working-13-k1hag7

this is the example of the problem. Here the API call is done.

plugin Docs - https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome

Answer (score 0):

you have to destroy the table before reload data

```
this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
        // Destroy the table first
        dtInstance.destroy();
        // Call the dtTrigger to rerender again
        this.dtTrigger.next();
      });
```